# How to get this function to work in Oracle 11G - PL/SQL

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

I'm new with PL/SQL I have a assignment where I need to make a function. The assignment is as follows:

> ```
> > "Create a function 'afdeling_van:'
> > - this function accepts a medewerkernummer(employee number) as argument
> > - give the afdelingnummer(department number) from the medewerkernummer(employee number) back"
> ```

So I need to create a function with a parameter that returns a number. After that I probably need to add some code to make it return a medewerker(employee) number back.

I got pretty stuck with this one as I am really new to PL/SQL. What I do have at the moment is this:

```
declare
 procedure afdeling_van(p_persoon in medewerkers.mnr%type)--table name with column name
 is
 begin
  select med.mnr
  from medewerkers med;
  where mnr = p_persoon;
 end afdeling_van;
begin
afdeling_van(10);
end;
```

It's not working for me. I have tried different solutions. But as I lack experience and I cannot find the solution or information that I need on the web. I am trying it to ask here

one other thing. I think it's similair to my problem. In the previous assignment I made a procedure instead of a function. The procedure is as follows:

```
declare
v_medewerker varchar2(50) := ontsla_med();
 procedure ontsla_med(p_medewerkers in medewerkers.naam%type)
 is 
 begin
  delete from medewerkers
  where naam = p_medewerkers;
 end ontsla_med;
begin
ontsla_med('');
dbms_output.put_line('Medewerker: ' || v_medewerker || 'verwijdert uit medewerker, inschrijven en uitvoeringen bestand.' );
 exception
  when no_data_found then
  dbms_output.put_line('Medewerker bestaat niet/ is al verwijderd.');
end;
/
```

this works except for the last dbms_output.put_line. If I remove the output line, then it will work and with the output line, it won't.

I hope my question is not too vague.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function instead of a procedure, and you've got a semi-colon in the wrong place. Try something like:

```
declare
  nReturned_value  MEDEWERKERS.AFDELINGNUMMER%TYPE;

  FUNCTION afdeling_van(p_persoon in medewerkers.mnr%type) --table name with column name
      RETURN MEDEWERKERS.AFDELINGNUMMER%TYPE
  is
    nAFDELINGNUMMER  MEDEWERKERS.AFDELINGNUMMER%TYPE;
  begin
    select med.AFDELINGNUMMER
      INTO nAFDELINGNUMMER  
      from medewerkers med
      where mnr = p_persoon;

    RETURN nAFDELINGNUMMER  ;
  end afdeling_van;

begin
  nReturned_value := afdeling_van(10);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nReturned_value = ' || nReturned_value);
end;
```

### Edit

In your second example, I don't believe that the line `v_medewerker varchar2(50) := ontsla_med();` will compile. `ontsla_med` is a procedure rather than a function, and because procedures don't return anything they can't be used in an assignment statement.

However, `v_medewerker` is only used in the `DBMS_OUTPUT` line which you say causes a problem - thus, it may be that the compiler is eliminating the variable because it's not used if the `DBMS_OUTPUT` line is removed, thus eliminating the problem. Try changing the declaration to `v_medwerker varchar2(50) := 'Hello';` and see if that helps.

Comment: Your solution works! thanks for the code. With your example I understand where it went wrong for me. So thanks for that! 

If I may ask. Do you have any idea how to solve the other problem that I have?

ps: I mark your awnser as the right given awnser to my problem

Comment: @MaximedeLange - I've edited the answer to address the second issue. Best of luck.